# C# - Azure Function issue

Tags: c#, php, azure

I am new to coding and not familar with C#. However, I have a PHP script that I am trying to convert to C# to use in Azure Function that will trigger every 15 mins. I have the first section and function of the code and it compiles and produces a success in the Azure Function console but does not provide the result in an output. below is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
{
log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");    
}
{
using (var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler())
{
httpClientHandler.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))    
{
var response = 
httpClient.GetAsync("https://auth.bullhornstaffing.com/oauth/authorize?
client_id=****type=code&username=*****&password=*****&action=Login").Result;
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Found)
{
var redirectUrl = response.Headers.Location;
var startIndex = redirectUrl.Query.IndexOf("code=") + 5;
var endIndex = redirectUrl.Query.IndexOf("&", startIndex);
var authorizationCode = (redirectUrl.Query.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - 
startIndex));
}
}
}
    }
```

If I remove the var authorizationCode I get error that it does not have a namespace and if I return it or response I do not get any output.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

httpClient.GetAsync is an asynchronous statement, which means that the code is continuing without waiting for the webrequest to finish. Wait for GetAsync and then you can continue:

```
var task = httpClient.GetAsync("https://auth.bullhornstaffing.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=****type=code&username=*****&password=*****&action=Login");
task.Wait();
var response = task.Result;
```

There are also two brackets too much (lines 12&13) and I guess you want to access the ContentLocation of the httpContent?

Probably that's the right one:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;

public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");    

    using (var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler())
    {
        httpClientHandler.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
        {
            log.Info("get async...");
            var task = httpClient.GetAsync("https://auth.bullhornstaffing.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=****type=code&username=*****&password=*****&action=Login");
            task.Wait();

            var response = task.Result;
            var httpContent = response.Content;
            log.Info("Result: " + httpContent.Headers.ContentLocation);

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Found)
            {
                var redirectUrl = httpContent.Headers.ContentLocation;
                var startIndex = redirectUrl.Query.IndexOf("code=") + 5;
                var endIndex = redirectUrl.Query.IndexOf("&", startIndex);
                var authorizationCode = (redirectUrl.Query.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it now waits and prints result but doesnt pick up on the code in the url returned. But thank you.